# How to detect attribute changes after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying display a ***link*** in the view page with the below condition.

```
<% if @user.primary_phone_changed? %>
---link here---
<% end %>
```

But the attribute `primary_phone` is ***only available on edit*** and the value is updated after the update action is called. So I'm unable to use [***Dirty***](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) 's `changed?` method here. Is there any method/way to track attribute changes after update?

Comment: Maybe `@user.previous_changes` can help? See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes

Comment: @EgonWilzer Nope! `@user.previous_changes` returns an empty `{}`. My problem is I'm calling `update` not `save`.

Comment: @Pavan please have try `@user.changes` See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes

Comment: @Prashant4020 It returns empty `{}` too.

Comment: @Pavan That means `@user` object unaltered

Comment: @Prashant4020 No. I've updated `primary_phone` field of `users` table for that particular `@user` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, the change list is reset after the update is completed. Your best option is to define an attribute in the model (it could be a boolean for example) and you use an `after_update` callback to set it to true/false whenever the attribute you want to track changed.

In that way, you'll be able to query that instance variable and check if the model changed.

Comment: Hmmm. This seems the way. Thanks.