# Rails 4 Check attribute with _changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i would like check if an attribute was changed by the user with : _changed?

Controller :

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident.update(incident_params)
        if :tech_id_changed?
          @incident.update(evenement_type_user: 2)
          @incident.update(evenement_type_tech: 2)
        else
          @incident.update(evenement_type_user: 1)
          @incident.update(evenement_type_tech: 1)
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident mis à jour.' }

        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @incident }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But

```
if :tech_id_changed?
```

Return always true, even if tech_id has not changed.

Why ?

Nope, is not working. Supposed i would change the title of the incident. I can do this ?

```
      before_update :on_before_update

  def on_before_update
    if self.tech_id_changed?
      self.evenement_type_user = '2'
      self.evenement_type_tech = '2'
    else
      self.evenement_type_user = 1
      self.evenement_type_tech = 1
    end
  end
```

My update function in my controller re-attribute the `evenement_type_user` to 1 :

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident.update(incident_params)
        if @incident.tech_id_changed?
          @incident.update(evenement_type_user: 2)
          @incident.update(evenement_type_tech: 2)
        else
          @incident.update(evenement_type_user: 1)
          @incident.update(evenement_type_tech: 1)
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident mis à jour.' }

        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @incident }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But if i delete

```
        if @incident.tech_id_changed?
      @incident.update(evenement_type_user: 2)
      @incident.update(evenement_type_tech: 2)
    else
      @incident.update(evenement_type_user: 1)
      @incident.update(evenement_type_tech: 1)
    end
```

It works, I had forgotten to remove this piece of code.

So, Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:tech_id_changed?` is not a method. If you try:

```
:tech_id_changed?.class.name #=> Symbol
```

So your test will always pass, because falsy values in Ruby are only `false` itself and `nil`.

What you probably mean is:

```
if @incident.tech_id_changed?
  ...
end
```

Try to run under `rails c`:

```
incident = Incident.new
incident.tech_id_changed? # => false
incident.tech_id = 999999
incident.tech_id_changed? # => true
```

Also fix your model:

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :responses

  module Incidentmod
   attr_accessor :name, :content, :techidchanged
  end
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true


  ## I'm not sure what you are doing
  ## This is an example of how to use it properly

  before_update :on_before_update


  def on_before_update
    if self.tech_id_changed?
      self.evenement_type_user = '2'
      self.evenement_type_tech = '2'
    else
      self.evenement_type_user = 1
      self.evenement_type_tech = 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `if @incident.tech_id_changed` is always false, even if i change `@incident.tech_id`

Comment: @Sleed can you try an example in the end of my answer? You should get `true` in the end

Comment: Hmmm. `2.2.1 :001 > incident = Incident.first
NameError: uninitialized constant Incident
 from (irb):1
 from /home/jeremymontesinos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in <main>'
`

Comment: What's the name of the model for `@incident`?

Comment: `class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: You have error here: https://github.com/mjerem34/Tick-Master-/blob/master/app/models/incident.rb#L30

Comment: Yes, but i tried to understand the @pavan response. Can you explain me ?

Comment: What are you trying to understand?

Comment: @Sleed if you fix model, like I did in answer it works!

Comment: It already worked for me. Do you still have problem with your code?

Comment: Nope, is not working. Supposed i would change the title of the incident.
I can do this ? :
`before_update :on_after_update

  def on_after_update
    if self.tech_id_changed?
      self.evenement_type_user = '2'
      self.evenement_type_tech = '2'
    else
      self.evenement_type_user = 1
      self.evenement_type_tech = 1
    end
  end`

Comment: @Sleed sorry i misspelled method name. Please copy it again. It should work now

Comment: Yes i now, but even with the good method name it fail. I updated my first message with model

Comment: I would update an other attribute if an first attribute is updated.

Comment: Not for me ... Can you send me your model file ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [**Dirty**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) documentation this line `if :tech_id_changed?` should be `if @incident.tech_id_changed?`

Comment: if it's `if @incident.tech_id_changed?` it's always false

Comment: @Sleed Myself had the same problem, the explanation in [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241979/how-to-detect-attribute-changes-after-update) answer could help you.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand everything, my model : `class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :responses

  module Incidentmod
    attr_accessor :name, :content, :techidchanged
  end
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true

  after_update :techidchanged = true, :if => @incident.title_changed?
end
`

Answer (score 0):

@pavan:

My model :

```
    class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :responses

  module Incidentmod
    attr_accessor :name, :content, :techidchanged
  end
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true

  after_update :techidchanged = true, :if => @incident.tech_id_changed?
end
```

Comment: You should post this as an update in the question, not as an answer :)